# Formatting URLs with .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, search

I have a search engine script that formats it's URLs from a .htaccess file. However, when a search is made on the site, the search URL has /search/QUERY%20TERMS/1/. (Notice the %20 in between each word). Is there any way with PHP or .htaccess that I can have + instead of %20?

My .htaccess code is currently this. It formats the SERP URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&category=web&d=$2
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/$ /search/$1/1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)$ /search/$1/1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

And my PHP code is currently this. It allows the search box to go to the correct SERP as it has a complicated URL structure.

```
<?PHP
if( isset( $_POST['q'] ) )
{
    header( 'location: search/' . $_POST['q'] . '/1/' );
    exit();
}
?>
```

How can I get my URLs to have + instead of %20 in PHP or .htaccess?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.
Callum

Comment: How are you starting the search on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [`urlencode()` (man page)](http://php.net/urlencode) it before performing your redirect like so:

```
<?PHP
if( isset( $_POST['q'] ) )
{
    header( 'location: search/' . urlencode($_POST['q']) . '/1/' );
    exit();
}
?>
```

This doesn't have anything to do with .htaccess or mod_rewrite. It is about the URL being passed to the server in the correct format in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `urlencode()` would be to transliterate the space for another character. For example wikipedia uses the `_` underscore in place of spaces, which would look nicer than the `+` from urlencode.

```
header( 'location: search/' . (strtr($_POST['q'], " ", "_")) . '/1/' );
// actually you should still apply urlencode() for other special chars
```

Of course this necessitates undoing the same in the search script:

```
$q = strtr($_GET["q"], "_", " ");
```